# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return selectAddress }

Tags: magento2, shipping, knockoutjs, shipping-address

My checkout page is customized. Now after the upgrade when I tried to access the checkout page its showing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return selectAddress }` , I have checked the `shipping.js` and its have the required method like this :

```
 selectAddress: function (address) {
             console.log(address.getKey());
            selectShippingAddress(address);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(address.getKey());
        }
```

What could be the reason for not accessing the function? any help
[image]

Comment: Have you checked if any module's rewrite the shipping.js or your theme?
Take a look inside requirejs-config.js for any rewrite's

Comment: @AlanZavagli this is from a custom theme. Means it's overrieded one.

Comment: The issues could be 2, the theme is no more overriding the shipping.js, or the upgrade changed some js's, could you please check your shipping.js in the google developer tools to check where it's getting the code?

Comment: When I move the method to top area in shipping.js I got error in chrome console. Its means its still calling the js file

Comment: In google developer -> network -> filter for shipping.js, could you please check inside the response for the method? I've checked inside shipping.js (Magento base) there's not that method, (version 2.3.5)

Comment: @AlanZavagli getting in-network console. Please check the screenshot https://prnt.sc/1pqp669

Comment: Ok, check the response for the missing method, https://prnt.sc/1pqz0d1

Comment: @AlanZavagli its exist in file:  https://prnt.sc/1pr1ogr

Comment: Searching a bit, there could be an issue on the template.html that you're calling, as some documentation and Magento code that i've seen you should try to change the data-bind with: data-bind="click: selectAddress" or data-bind="click: $parent.selectAddress()"

Comment: @AlanZavagli Ok let me try.thanks

Comment: You need the "knockout context debugger" extension for google chrome. This helpful extension will let you know which component (aka js file) is being used by the element observing the clicks. That should provide a quick answer.